# Juniper Network Connect (VPN) on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, 64-bit, vpn

My company uses Juniper networks for vpn access. I am unable to get the juniper network connect client to work on windows 7 64-bit. It used to work before but after I formatted my system it gives the following error every time I start the vpn client

[image]

If I check the logs I see this error

> The Juniper Network Connect Service
>   service is marked as an interactive
>   service.  However, the system is
>   configured to not allow interactive
>   services.  This service may not
>   function properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. You need to have SP1 installed and automatic updates does not do this for you.

Answer (score 3):

[Windows 7 and Juniper Network Connect 6.3 - Tech & Computer Forums](http://www.tech-forums.net/forums/f27/windows-7-juniper-network-connect-6-3-a-214565/)

Try the links from the above post and download Juniper Networks Version 6.3. It will work, because it worked for me:

- [Windows 7 32-bit](http://portalcontent.johnshopkins.edu/sslvpn/JHconnectInstaller/JHConnectForWindows-6.3.0-SAI.exe)
- [Windows 7 64-bit](http://portalcontent.johnshopkins.edu/sslvpn/JHconnectInstaller/JHConnectForWindows64bit-6.3.0-SAI.exe)

Comment: Might bring the relevant info to your answer. Just in case that other forum gets rot, withers and dies :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this: [JHConnect Installers](http://portalcontent.johnshopkins.edu/sslvpn/installers.html)

Install the second link (Microsoft Windows 64-bit (Including XP, Vista, and Windows 7)) at your own risk and follow the instructions.

This worked perfectly for me. I was struggling with 64 bit for quite some time and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you like me whom the answer didn't work, this might:

- Open services (Start->Rune "services.msc").
- Look for "Juniper Network Connect Service"
- If it is stopped, try to start it.
- If it does not start, check the "Path to executable:" in the service dialog box.
- If path is incorrect, open registry:
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\dsNcService`
- Fix the path.
- Start dsNetworkConnect.exe (or otherwise launch Juniper network client)

Thanks to the excellent tool '[Serviwin](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/serviwin.html)' by nirsofer

Answer (score 0):

I posted about this in detail [on my blog](http://wiredmouse.blogspot.in/2012/06/juniper-network-connect-for-windows-7.html):

> Installation Procedure:
>
> Step 1: Uninstall the previous versions of
>   Juniper Network Connect. (If you ever tried connecting your office
>   computer then you might have installed this software on your machine.
>   Check in Add or remove programs)
>
> Step 2: Go to Computer and click on Organise-->Folders and search
>   options --> View tab --> Under Hidden files and folders, click on Show
>   hidden files, folders, and drives and click on OK.
>
> Step 2: Now you have to delete some files on your machine. Go to
>   Computer--> Local Disk (C:) --> Users --> "Click on your username"(If
>   you are not sure of your username, then click on start. You will find
>   your username on top of Documents)
>
> Step 3: Click on AppData folder (hidden folder) --> Roaming --> Delete
>   the Juniper Networks folder.
>
> Step 4: Install the Juniper Networks software which you have
>   downloaded from the above link. (Click Yes for all the authentication
>   messages)
>
> Step 5: Now Run the software. Go to Start-->All Programs-->Juniper
>   Networks--> Network Connect 6.30.-->Network Connect
>
> Step 6: Now enter the VPN address and sign in.

Comment: Answers should stand on their own. Answers that contain no useful information except what's behind a link are not good answers. Further, this looks like you're trying to drive traffic to your site, which many people will consider spam. Worse, when that link stops working this answer is worthless.